# SQL Server always-on using WSFC

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a question about SQL Server Always on using Windows Server Failover Cluster(WSFC).

I have 5 SQL Server instances in 2 datacenters using 2 subnets.

My data centers:

```
DC1 (192.168.1.0/24), DC2 (192.168.2.0/24)
```

My SQL Server instances:

```
DB1-DC1(Primary), DB2-DC1(Secondary), DB3-DC1(Async), DB1-DC2(Secondary), DB2-DC2(Secondary)
```

When DC2 goes down everything is ok and my cluster role is up, but when DC1 goes down my cluster role goes down too.

What do I have to do to have maximum fault tolerance in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the cluster shuts down is because it doesn't have enough quorum votes. I am assuming the cluster is configured as node majority without a witness.

That means there are a total of 5 quorum votes - one for each node.  When DC2 goes down - you have 3 of 5 quorum votes which is more than 50% and cluster is healthy.

When DC1 goes down - you have 2 of 5 quorum votes which is less than 50% and the cluster is not healthy.  For a cluster to be healthy is needs to have more than 50% quorum votes.

You should review this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/understand-quorum

Adding either a file or cloud witness that is accessible from DC2 should resolve the issue.  You definitely should review and consider dynamic witness and dynamic quorum for this cluster.

Comment: Thank you for answer
but that’s the point, when I add a witness and then DC1 goes down now I have 2 vote(instances) + 1 vote(witness), now I have 3 vote in DC1 and 3 vote in DC2 what happened now when DC1 is up and just connection between two site is down? Instances in DC1 wats to be primary and servers in DC2 wants to be primary too

Comment: You could remove the quorum vote from DB3-DC1 so the cloud quorum provides a tie-breaker.  Or just accept that a failover to DC2 would require manual intervention.  What if DC1 becomes disconnected from the internet and DC2 but your users and apps still can connect to DC1?  You might not even want automated failover to DC2.

Comment: thank you too
but if i remove the quorum vote from db3-dc1 now i have 2 vote in dc1 and if dc2 goes down cluster goes down too
i think i find my answer i have to move db3-dc1 to another datacenter in this position i have 2 vote in dc1 and 2 vote in dc2 when dc1 goes down dc2 + db3-dc3 become 3 vote and when dc2 goes down dc1 + db3-dc3 become 3 vote
or in another solution i have to remove db3-dc1 quorum vote and add a witness in another datacenter